# Add UIDatePicker to UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview, uidatepicker

I am trying to add a date picker to an alert view.  I can add the animation to the screen based on a button click and I see a black box but no date picker.

Here is what I have so far....

```
- (IBAction)showDatePicker {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(200, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 0);  //CGRectMake(225, 145, 260, 125);
    UIPickerView *datePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    UIAlertView *showDateAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Enter the Code Date"
                                  message:@"Sample message"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Update", nil];

    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"slideIn" context:nil];
    [datePicker setCenter:CGPointMake(datePicker.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height - datePicker.frame.size.height/2)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I found an example that appears to be working BUT I don't see any dialog or buttons in my alert box, just the date picker itself.  Am I missing something here?

```
- (IBAction)showDatePicker {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(225, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 125);
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

    UIAlertView *alert;
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
             initWithTitle:@"Enter the Code Date"
             message:@"Sample message"
             delegate:self
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
             otherButtonTitles:@"Update", nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert addSubview:datePicker];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the commenters who have been saying this is not the way to accomplish this, for a couple reasons. First, no-one likes having alert-views constantly popping up. Second, and not applicable to your situation, It might eventually cause an app to be rejected. Apple has changed the wording in the `UIAlertView` class reference referring to its view hierarchy as private; And we all know how apple feels about you mucking about in what they consider private.

> From UIAlertView class reference:
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

But since you say this is a private app, here goes. A `UIAlertView` is just a `UIView` subclass. So all of the rules of frames and bounds still apply. Here's a basic sample of how to adjust the frame of the picker and bounds of the alert to squeeze in the date picker.

```
// Create alert
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
// Show alert (required for sizes to be available)
[alert show];
// Create date picker (could / should be an ivar)
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, alert.bounds.size.height, 320, 216)];
// Add picker to alert
[alert addSubview:picker];
// Adjust the alerts bounds
alert.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 + 20, alert.bounds.size.height + 216 + 20);
```

**EDIT**

As has been noted by both comments and new answers to many of the 'how do I add some view to a `UIAlertView`' questions, this method no longer works in iOS7 and above. This should really be taken as evidence that this is a fundamentally bad idea.

Also note the usage of `setValue:forKey:` in the generally circulated "solution" to the "problem" of not being able to modify Apple's private view hierarchy. `setValue:forKey:` is one of those methods that draws the interest of the private API scanners. Go search for `accessoryView` in the `UIAlertView` documentation and headers. It's not in the docs. The only related item in the headers is an ivar named `_accessoryView` which is marked as `@private`.

Again for an in-house or private app I suppose it's okay, just okay though.

Comment: Thank you NJones, this is what I was looking for.  I understand what everyone is saying here.  I will take that into consideration.

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift:**

```
        let myDatePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        // setting properties of the datePicker
        myDatePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        myDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 15, 270, 200)

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.view.addSubview(myDatePicker)
        let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(somethingAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to like this answer, but my suggestion is: don't do that! UIAlertView is not intended for you to add your own subviews; examples that you find of people doing that are examples of wrong behavior. Create your own view containing the picker, text, buttons, etc. that you want, and present it somehow. For example you could present it modally via its own view controller, e.g. with `presentModalViewController:animated:` or `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. If you're on an iPad, you could use a popover (it can be modal if that's important).

Comment: I have a split view controller and on the right side I need to allow the user to select a date.  There are several other items the user will need to fill in.  I really don't like the size of the date picker and I have been trying to find a better way but have not seen any examples.  Can my sample be reworked to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Ummm, why?  From a usability POV if all I want to do is allow the user to select a date it makes sense.  This is a private app.  I don't really need people to tell me what NOT to do.  I'd like to know HOW to do it please.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (using iOS7). Call this before `[alertView show]`:

```
[alertView setValue:customContentView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

---

**Example:**

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[av setValue:v forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[av show];
```

Source: [iOS 7 UIDatePicker in UIAlertView customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067631/1533054)

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me in ios7 and above.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Date" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, alert.bounds.size.height, 320, 216)];
[alert addSubview:picker];
alert.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 + 20, alert.bounds.size.height + 216 + 20);
[alert setValue:picker forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

Comment: @Neela Yours Welcome !

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5** version of @Matheus Domingos answer

```swift
let myDatePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
myDatePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
myDatePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: 270, height: 200)
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
alertController.view.addSubview(myDatePicker)
let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(somethingAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
present(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})
```

**Swift 5.2**

```swift
let myDatePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
myDatePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
myDatePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: 270, height: 200)
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
alertController.view.addSubview(myDatePicker)
let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(somethingAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres my UIViewController Extension Solution.

```
typealias DatePickerHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ date:Date) -> Void
typealias TimePickerHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ date:Date) -> Void
extension UIViewController{

func showDatePicker(completionHandler: @escaping DatePickerHandler){
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 300)
    let pickerView = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vc.view.bounds.width, height: 300))
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        pickerView.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
     vc.view.addSubview(pickerView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        pickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.leadingAnchor,constant: 8),
        pickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.trailingAnchor,constant: 8),
        pickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.topAnchor,constant: 8),
        pickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.bottomAnchor,constant: 8),
    ])

       let editRadiusAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Date", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
       editRadiusAlert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
       editRadiusAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Select", style: .default, handler: {action in
        completionHandler(true,pickerView.date)
       }))
       editRadiusAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {action in
            completionHandler(false,Date())
       }))
       self.present(editRadiusAlert, animated: true)
}
func showTimePicker(completionHandler: @escaping TimePickerHandler){
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 300)
    let pickerView = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vc.view.bounds.width, height: 300))
    

    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.time
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        pickerView.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    vc.view.addSubview(pickerView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        pickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.leadingAnchor,constant: 8),
        pickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.trailingAnchor,constant: 8),
        pickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.topAnchor,constant: 8),
        pickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.bottomAnchor,constant: 8),
    ])
    

    let editRadiusAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Time", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
       editRadiusAlert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
       editRadiusAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Select", style: .default, handler: {action in
            completionHandler(true,pickerView.date)
        }))
        editRadiusAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {action in
             completionHandler(false,Date())
        }))
    
    self.present(editRadiusAlert, animated: true)
}
}
```

Here how to used it in UIViewController

```
    showDatePicker { (isSuccess, date) in
        if(isSuccess){
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding!