# Small Size-issue on UiPicker with in an Alert View (issue with height of the Alert View)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datepicker, uipickerview, uialertview

In my app I need to have a **Date Picker on UIAlert view**

I implemented this by following [Date Picker in Alert View](http://code.thewebanalyzers.com/2011/12/showing-datepicker-in-alert-view-without-using-interface/)

But while I'm using this date picker in alert view there **is some height issues in alert view** I tried to set the frame for the alert view but it doesn't sets what to do?

[image]

My code:

```
-(void)SetDate
{
      dobPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
      dobPicker.frame=CGRectMake(20, 25.0, 240.0, 150.0);
      dobPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;

      [dobPicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

            UIAlertView *dAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set Date" message:@"nnnnnnn" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Set Current Date" otherButtonTitles:@"Set New Date", nil];
   dAlert.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10.0, 300.0, 400.0);
  dAlert.delegate = self;
  [dAlert addSubview:dobPicker];
  [dAlert show];
  [dAlert release];
}


- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
      NSDate *date = [dobPicker date];
      NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
      [dateFormatter setDateFormat:(NSString*) @"yyyy-MM-dd"];

      NSLog(@"-------------------------- %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
}
```

Comment: ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166734/add-uidatepicker-to-uialertview                                   http://code.thewebanalyzers.com/2011/12/showing-datepicker-in-alert-view-without-using-interface/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add UIDatePicker to UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166734/add-uidatepicker-to-uialertview)

Answer (score 1):

`Transform` `Scale` your `UIAlertView` like this:

```
 dAlert.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(dAlert.transform,xScaleHere, yScaleHere); //provide your scaling points sx and sy according to your requirement.
```

Comment: message into english please

Answer (score 1):

simple: ... [UIAlertView..

> message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

...

also.. to view the title of UIAlertView.. try to modify "y" from 25 to 40.. (test)

> dobPicker.frame=CGRectMake(20, 40.0, ...

Comment: @user1811427 So..? what about?